# How to select specific Streetview panorama date?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-street-view

First of all I am not a programmer / coder, I'm a total noob HTML / JavaScript wise. So if possible please keep any answers simple ;-)

I'm working on a sort of hobby-art project. The goal is to compare Streetview panos of different dates and to create a photo gallery of these. I want to have a Streetview pano that is as clear as possible, so no UI.

What I have now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View controls</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initPano() {
        // Note: constructed panorama objects have visible: true
        // set by default.
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('map'), {
              position: {lat: 40.717215, lng: -74.0061689},
              addressControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
              },
              linksControl: false,
     addressControl: false,
              panControl: false,
              enableCloseButton: false
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAA3Rw1Ei8m79RwB_oapYe4rK5LgAbE7cg&signed_in=true&callback=initPano">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This HTML produces a nice clear Streetview pano without any UI. But I now would like to pull up a SV pano from a specific date.

I found this:
https://github.com/amenadiel/google-maps-documentation/blob/master/docs/StreetViewPanoramaData.md

and

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaData

I have no idea how / where to put this piece of code in my HTML.
- Can you show me where it needs to go?
- Perhaps you can create a HTML template where I only have to specify the latlongs / sv pano date?

Answer (score 1):

You can not select a specific date.

The StreetViewPanoramaData object REPRESENTS the data of Street View that is matched with panorama ID.

It means:

- copyright : Who copyright for this photo has.
- imageDate : When this photo was taken.
- links : What the next pano IDs are.
- location : Where this is.
- tiles: Tile data.

The StreetViewPanoramaData is used for creating custom street view typically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment wf9a5m75. Perhaps there is another way to select a specific image date.

For example in this URL I can see a date : sept 2009 (200709)

https://www.google.nl/maps/@40.7207836,-74.0006122,3a,75y,325.44h,102.22t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sqd5bzKg10n1SD0yG7vrjSg!2e0!5s20070901T000000!7i3328!8i1664?hl=nl

and

sept 2014 (201409)

https://www.google.nl/maps/@40.7207886,-74.000622,3a,75y,323.9h,97.02t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sYGwtmuZ4UHVYe5sDe_LIog!2e0!5s20140901T000000!7i13312!8i6656?hl=nl

Is there a way to put this in my custom URL above?

Comment: Link to tile URLs of Google Maps is against the Google Maps TOS. (Link to Google Maps page is ok, but link to image urls is prohibited.)
If you have special contract with Google, you might access to historical street view data (I did in a past project with G), but in public, there is no way currently except hacking (as far as I know).

Comment: @wf9a5m75 is there any documentation about "If you have special contract with Google, you might access to historical street view data" ?